# SharePoint 2010 list vew schema - View element

Tags: 2010, list, list-view

guys,

I am trying to understand list schema view. For example AnnouncementsList contains in schema 3 views:

```
<View BaseViewID="0" FreeForm="TRUE" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
<View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,camlid4;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="True" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/announce.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
<View BaseViewID="3" FreeForm="TRUE" Type="HTML" TabularView="FALSE">
```

But if we create announcement list, only one view will be availiable (view #1).
For what purposes other two views also included (#0 & #3)? And what does `FreeForm="TRUE"` mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is the type of toolbar that the list renders. it can be either standard or freeform.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543747.aspx

as for the views, they are providing additional functionality that you can access through other means.

so view 0 is the mobile view, not sure on view 3 but if you look at a form library you have a view foe relinking the form which you can do through list settings.

actually thinking about it view 3 is probably the summary view you get when you add the announcement list to a page.

Comment: Both #0 and #1 have `MobileView="TRUE"`. Also, #0 and #3 contain in definition a lot of CAML, including [Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411957.aspx) and [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442120.aspx) elements, so it really render something. If it's used as toolbar, why does field output included?. #1 doesn't contain such CAML. How can we use this enhanced CAML in #1?